# How to fix auto indent not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set 'Full' on Auto Indent option
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDEox.png)
But this option does not work when I add new line in any file, and no matter what language I'm using.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhteZ.gif)

I think when I press enter to add new line right after brackets or something, the editor should add tab automatically.
This is vscode running on other computer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TBxd.gif)

I deleted everything in setting.json file, but this problem is still appear.
How do I fix it?

(Sorry for my bad English. I'm not good at it :()

Comment: It might depend on the file type. Could you please check if VS Code correctly determined the file type? You can see it in the right part of the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code, head to Settings and search for tabSize. Uncheck the checkbox "Editor: Detect Indentation" and set a preferred value for "Editor: Tab Size" (e.g. 4). Restart VS Code and it should work.

Comment: Thx, that is working solution.